# javascript html text filter / linkify

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I'm trying to parse some HTML for links, the idea is to replace links to images with `<img>` and other links with `<a>`.

Basically I'm looking for something like this:

https://github.com/dejan/jquery-auto_html/blob/master/jquery.auto_html.js

But works on HTML as well as text. Meaning: it should replace `http://google.com` but not `<a href="http://google.com">google</a>`

Can I do this without lookbehinds being available in regex? Thanks.

We should go from

```
html = "Here is a great site: http://google.com!"
convert(html)
> "Here is a great site: <a href=\"http://google.com\">google</a>!"

html = "Here is a great site: <a href=\"http://google.com\">google</a>!"
convert(html)
> "Here is a great site: <a href=\"http://google.com\">google</a>!"
```

Comment: Lookbehind is best shot. `href="` part is confirmed to be there. So finding the text using this patter is the best way.

Comment: @Shiplu yes I know, just lookbehind is not support in javascript

Comment: Can you edit your question to include explicitly what html you want to convert? I am confused as to whether you are converting `a` elements to `img` elements or are converting text to `img` or `a` elements.

Comment: @mrtsherman added some examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex replacements will replace the links to `<a>` and image links to `<img>` elements. It excludes links that are already inside `href="` or `src="` etc..

```
function replaceStuff(html) {
  return html
         .replace(/[^\"]http(.*)\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)/g, ' <img src="http$1.$2">'
         .replace(/[^\"]http(.*)\.([a-zA-Z]*)/g, ' <a href="http$1.$2">http$1.$2</a>')
         );
}
```

You can call it like:

```
// will replace the link to <a>
replaceStuff('Hello http://google.com');

// will not replace anything
replaceStuff('Hello <a href="http://google.com">ff</a>');

// will replace image link to <img>
replaceStuff('Hello http://google.com/image.png');

// will not replace anything
replaceStuff('Hello <img src="http://google.com/image.png">');
```

Comment: And it excludes links in quotes. `My favorite site is "http://axels-fahrradladen.de"` will result in nothing changed.

Comment: Yeah, i wrote it so that it excludes links in quotes. The regex can be expanded to filter out just `href="..` and `src="..` instead of everything in quotes.

Comment: Cloned and corrected jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/uyixoq/2 - Source: http://jsbin.com/uyixoq/2/edit#source

Comment: There was a missing bracket after the first replace() and an extra closing bracket after the second! :-)